# Invalid Procedure error adding Custom Document Properties Programmatically

Tags: vba, excel, properties, runtime-error

I'm trying to use VBA to add Custom Document Properties to a new workbook that is being created by another sub. I'd like my code to add the property to the active workbook. The ultimate goal is that SharePoint reads these properties as the workbook is uploaded (working fine so far).

I am trying the code below with no luck and keep getting the error "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add "Part Number", True, _
    msoPropertyTypeString, "PartNumberMetadata.Value"
```

> `Name of Doc Property = "Part Number"`
>   `Linked to Content = True`
>   `Doc Property Type = msoPropertyTypeString`
>   `Value = "PartNumberMetadata" '(A named range in my workbook)`

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If your code is dealing with multiple workbooks, it's possible that the `ActiveWorkbook` might not be what you're expecting. Have you verified that? (One way to verify, add `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name`, somewhere in that sub.) I would personally pass the workbook into the sub as a parameter. That way I could ensure that it's referencing the correct workbook (and makes the sub for flexible for reuse, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameters incorrect.

basically:

- if `LinkToContent` =`True`, then the `LinkSource` argument is required.
- if `LinkToContent` = `False`, then the `Value` argument is required.

### Syntax:

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add (Name, LinkToContent, [Type], _
    [Value], [LinkSource])
```

---

### Value

The data value of the `Value` property, if it's not linked to the contents of the container document. The value is converted to match the data type specified by the Type argument, and if it can't be converted, an error occurs.

**If `LinkToContent` is `True`, the argument is ignored** and the new document property is assigned a default value until the linked property values are updated by the container application (usually when the document is saved).

---

### LinkSource

**Ignored if `LinkToContent` is `False`.** The source of the `LinkSource` property. The container application determines what types of source linking you can use.

For example, **DDE** links use the `Server|Document!Item` syntax.

---

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/documentproperties-add-method-office) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer to my issue!